# Can't override function with generic parameter

Tags: swift, generics, overriding

Context:

I have class A which is a superclass for class B. Class A also has generic types declared in the class declaration which are overriden by it's child classes.

Class A has a method which requires a generic parameter which is not part of the class declaration.

Class B overrides the class definition by specifying the generic types from the class definition and wants to override the generic function.

Example:

```
class A<U: NSDictionary, Z: NSDictionary> : NSObject
{
    func funcToOverride<T : JSONModel>()
    {

    }
}

class B : A<NSDictionary, NSDictionary>
{
    override func funcToOverride<T:JSONModel>()
    {

    }
}
```

Problem:

Class B cannot override the method with compiler error "Method does not override any method from its superclass"

Question:

1) Why is this occurring in the first place?

2) Is there any known ways to avoid this problem? My superclass is superclass for other child classes as well besides B so adding a generic param in class definition is problematic just for defining a type for a single function.

Additional notes:

This code is strictly! a sample from a much more complex code I am working with inside an existing big SDK. I need to specifically solve the generics conflict problem by avoiding adding protocols or other classes which are not related to the current context.

*As requested in case somebody feels the need for a bigger context*

**A more extended sample version:**

```
class A<ResponseModel : NSDictionary, RedirectModel : NSDictionary>: NSObject {

    let existingCompletionHandler : (responseModel : ResponseModel?, error : NSError?) -> Void = {
        (responseModel : ResponseModel?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
    }

    func presentWebViewAndWaitForRedirect(redirectQueryPath : String)
    {
        let queryPathToDict : [NSObject : AnyObject] = [:]

        treatRedirectWithResponseParams(queryPathToDict) {[weak self] (model, error) in
            self?.callSomeRandomRequestWithRedirectModel(model)
        }
    }

    func callSomeRandomRequestWithRedirectModel(redirectModel : RedirectModel?)
    {
        let requestResult : [NSObject : AnyObject] = [:]

        treatRequestResponse(requestResult, completionHandler: existingCompletionHandler)
    }

    func treatRedirectWithResponseParams(responseParams : [NSObject : AnyObject], completionHandler : (model : RedirectModel?, error : NSError?) -> Void)
    {
        funcToOverride(responseParams, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    func treatRequestResponse(someRequestResult : [NSObject : AnyObject], completionHandler : (model : ResponseModel?, error : NSError?) -> Void)
    {
        funcToOverride(someRequestResult, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    func funcToOverride<T : NSDictionary>(params : [NSObject : AnyObject], completionHandler : (model : T?, error : NSError?) -> Void)
    {

    }
}


class B: A<NSDictionary, NSDictionary> {

        //wants to provide something additional or different to the base implementation but still respect the base class logic flow
        override func funcToOverride<T : NSDictionary>(params: [NSObject : AnyObject], completionHandler: (model: T?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {

        }
    }

class SomeOtherRandomClass : NSDictionary
{

}

class C: A<NSDictionary, NSDictionary> {

    func someOtherClassCRequest()
    {
        let response : [NSObject : AnyObject] = [:]

        funcToOverride(response) { (model : SomeOtherRandomClass?, error : NSError?) in

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it is shown here, the code makes little sense. Your question is missing some information What is `JSONModel`? What  other types conform to or inherit from `JSONModel`? What is the purpose of `T`? It is not being passed as a function parameter, so how is it being used?

Comment: The sample is to show the problem. You can replace whatever classes you want if they follow the logic in the sample. Somewhere "there" the type T is determined by other functions which call this generic one. And the T is generic because it has around 3 different types to which it will be "converted" depending on the callee function. Anyways, other types which inherit from JSONModel or other functions which call this function is not relevant for the stated problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming you are actually using type T somewhere, although your code example does not show this.*

You do not need to use generics.

In one use case, the input type T is always defined as a JSONModel, so the function will never be able to specialise to access any additional properties or methods except those defined on JSONModel. Whatever types you are referencing, need to conform to JSONModel (either through inheritance, or as a protocol). You might as well just use JSONModel.

The only other use case is that you need to access specific members of an instances of JSONModel, in which case you can use function overloading.

Example:

```
protocol JSONModel {
    func hello() -> String
}

class ModelA: JSONModel {
    func hello() -> String {
        return "Hello Model A"
    }
}

class ModelB: JSONModel {
    func hello() -> String {
        return "Hello Model B"
    }

    func goodbye() -> String {
        return "Goodbye Model B"
    }
}

class A<U: NSDictionary, Z: NSDictionary>: NSObject
{
    func fromJSON(t: JSONModel)
    {
        print("From A: \(t.hello())")
    }
}

class B : A<NSDictionary, NSDictionary>
{
    override func fromJSON(t: JSONModel)
    {
        print("From B: \(t.hello())")
    }

    func fromJSON(t: ModelB)
    {
        print("From B: \(t.goodbye())")
    }
}

let a = A()
a.fromJSON(ModelA()) // "From A: Hello A"

let b = B()
b.fromJSON(ModelB() as JSONModel) // "From B: Hello B"
b.fromJSON(ModelB()) // "From B: Goodbye B"
```

Comment: I offered just the simplest representation of my code. In practice I need to specifically have the type T in order to serialize it to the correct instance. The functions which are not showed in the sample use this generic function and pass in a specific type, thus determining how the instance will be serialised. Anyways that's a long story. The idea is I need the code in the way specified above and I'm searching for solving this generic conflict by not adding other protocols/classes as this is a huge SDK and changes like this require also some other "architecture" changes.

Comment: Still this is an interesting idea in case smb has the flexibility of a simpler code and the ability to add considerable changes.

Comment: Please clarify your question to show how you are using `T`, or why it is defined as a generic on the function.

Comment: I added some more context. Hope it helps.

Comment: Again, the NSDictionary as a generic type is just for the purpose of putting a class there. In reality it's a base model class from which other model classes inherit.

Answer (score 1):

You can just leave off the `override` keyword. Inheritance works normally.

```
import Cocoa
import XCPlayground## Heading ##

class JSONModel {
    required init() {
    }
}

class ModelA: JSONModel {
    var name: String?
    required init() {
    }
}

class ModelB: JSONModel {
    var size: Int?
    required init() {
    }
}

class A<U: NSDictionary, Z: NSDictionary>: NSObject
{
    let prefix = "A"

    func funcToOverride<T: JSONModel>(u: [String: AnyObject], c: (T?) -> Void)
    {
        let t = T()
        (t as? ModelA)?.name = "From A: " + ((u["name"] as? String) ?? "-none-")
        (t as? ModelB)?.size = u["size"] as? Int ?? 0
        c(t)
    }
}

class B : A<NSDictionary, NSDictionary>
{
    let suffix = "B"

    func funcToOverride<T: JSONModel>(u: [String: AnyObject], c: (T?) -> Void)
    {
        let t = T()
        (t as? ModelA)?.name = "From B: " + ((u["name"] as? String) ?? "-none-")

        if t is ModelB {
            return super.funcToOverride(u, c: c)
        }

        c(t)
    }
}

let a = A()

a.funcToOverride(["name": "foo"]) { (m: ModelA?) in
    print("From A: \(m) \(m?.name)")
}

a.funcToOverride(["size": 10]) { (m: ModelB?) in
    print("From A: \(m) \(m?.size)")
}


let b = B()

b.funcToOverride(["name": "bar"]) { (m: ModelA?) in
    print("From B: \(m) \(m?.name)")
}

b.funcToOverride(["size": 10]) { (m: ModelB?) in
    print("From B: \(m) \(m?.size)")
}

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: Using the code provided in my sample, I've just used the method without override [in the B class] and put a print there. Then created an instance of B and called treatRequestResponse on it. The method from B was not called, instead the method from A was called.